# Imagem de background distorcida no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Pessoal criei uma imagem para o background do meu app, fiz ela de acordo com a resolução do smartphone que estava testando, porém ficou distorcida, depois me lembrei que estava usando a ActionBar, logo a tela do app fica menor.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tem como obter o tamanho do tela que não seja em Fullscreen, e sim com a ActionBar, no caso a partir da actionbar para baixo?

Estou trabalhando da forma correta na criação do background? Tipo simplesmente pego a resolução do smart e faço ou existe outra maneira melhor?

LogCat respondendo ao sicachester:

`04-22 16:42:53.965    1256-1256/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
            at com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha.Main.clickQuadrado(Main.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: Não entendi o porque voce quer pegar o tamanho da tela pra baixo da action bar.

Comment: Olá amigo... bom talvez eu esteja errado mas é o seguinte. Criei um bakground conforme o tamanho da tela, como se fosse ficar fullscreen, porém tem a action bar, dai o background começa a partir da Action Bar se tornando menor a area do aplicativo diferente do que estivesse em fullscreen. Suponho que seja esse o loyivo da imagem que fiz fica um pouco fora forma, ficou meio "espremida"

Comment: Suponho que seja esse o problema*

Comment: posta uma fota da imagem normal, e depois de como ficou no app

Answer (score 3):

Fazer qualquer imagem, seja de background ou não, com o tamanho específico do device que você está testando é bem arriscado. Você nunca poderá garantir que a imagem fique perfeita em todos os cenários. Por mais que os aparelhos tenham o mesmo tamanho de tela, a densidade entre eles são diferentes, o que também não irá garantir a mesma qualidade de sua imagem.

Perceba que, na grande maioria dos apps, o background da aplicação é "chapado", ou seja, uma cor sólida apenas.

Entretanto, caso você precise te uma imagem como background de sua aplicação, te recomendo duas opções:

1) Extraia uma imagem para cada densidade e as as coloque nas pastas especificas (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi etc.).

2) Extraia uma simples e grande imagem e use um `ImageView`, com o atributo `scaleType` como `centerCrop`, e aplique sua imagem nela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_example"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas acho que meu Android Studio esteja configurado de forma errada ou sei lá, pois não encontro as pastas drawable com a resoluções, há somente uma drawable que está vazia

Comment: @Ablon estas pastas não são criadas automaticamente, depende do desenvolvedor cria-las. Dê uma olhada na documentação de como cria-las: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Ata, bom é que via nos tutorias que elas já eram criadas ao iniciar o projeto. Em casa vou tentar, obrigado!

Comment: Bom criei elas, antes, eu estava setando uma imagem no ImageButton que estava na pasta drawable (a única que tinha), daí agora criei as pastas com as diferentes resoluções e botei em cada uma a imagem conforme o DPI. Porém o app quebra no momento em que a imagem deveria aparecer, há alguma forma diferente de fazer quando se trabalha com varias pastas drawable?

Comment: @Ablon qual o erro que aparece no Logcat?

Comment: Está em minha pergunta...