# Centrar imagem de background

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou a tentar meter como imagem de background uma imagem que quero que fique exactamente centrada verticalmente e horizontalmente (a imagem é uma bola). Portanto o objectivo é ficar horizontalmente `match_parent` e verticalmente `wrap_content` para que fique bemno centro do ecrã.

Não estou a conseguir este efeito porque tambem estou a usar a Toolbar e ao conseguir colocar a imagem bem a Toolbar vem também para o centro.
Alguém me pode ajudar por favor?

Código:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ball"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/grey0">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"> (...) </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Experimente tirar o atributo `android:layout_gravity` do *Toolbar*.

Comment: @ramaral, fica igual :\

Comment: Olá, de uma olhada no item 2) desta resposta e veja se te ajuda! O conceito é o mesmo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59276/imagem-de-background-distorcida-no-android-studio/59336#59336

Comment: @sicachester mas ao utilizar o ImageView como é que colocas a imagem como background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é organizar suas `View's` em "camadas", tendo um `ImageView` ao fundo, com o `Drawable` que tem a imagem que quer centralizar. Fazendo isso você pode centralizar uma certa "camada" sem interferir no alinhamento das demais `View's`.

Usando o `FrameLayout` ficaria:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Primeira "camada", com o ImageView que vai ficar centrado ao fundo -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ball" />

    <!-- Segunda camada com o conteudo a frente do ImageView -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/grey0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Restante das views -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Para entender melhor o `FrameLayout`, recomendo uma visita a essa pergunta: [Como deixar imageView atras dos botoes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48356/como-deixar-imageview-atras-dos-botoes/48365#48365).

Comment: Muito Obrigada!